# Salesforce manage community users without managing other users

Tags: community, user-management

My requirement is to allow a user with a "Standard User" profile (Salesforce License) to create a community user.  To do this I need to give the user "Manage User" permission. But doing this the "View Setup and Configuration" permission also gets activated in the permission set. Because of which this user will me able to make changes to other users as well.

Is there a way in which I can allow this user to create the Community User but not allow him to make changes for other type of users.

Comment: Don't you just need to grant "Manage External Users" rather than "Manage Users" to allow community user creation?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I tried. Works only as long as I don't implement CRUD FLS. Once I do a CRUD FLS check, I am not able to create the Community User

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try using permission set if that does not work then you can write custom page that will allow user to create new community customer.

Make sure that controller for this page is written without sharing so it will run in System mode and will have full access.

Then allow user with "Standard User" profile to access this page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply AtulRajguru9. Yes I can implement your solution. Another solution I know thats working is to disable CRUD FLS check while creating a new community user. But I believe both these solutions will fail in the salesforce security review. Infact using a controller without using "with sharing" will also show as a security violation in the security scanner report.

Comment: did you tried permission set?

Comment: Yes I have. "Manage User" permission is there is Permission sets itself